# Unmapped property in a mapped class (Fluent NHibernate 1.1)

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

### Background

Fluent NHibernate 1.1 (with a repository implementation using LINQ to NHibernate) in an ASP.NET MVC 2 project using Ninject.

I have a mapped class (`Station`) with a collection of another mapped class (`Report`). I would also like `Station` to have a convenience property (`MostRecentReport`) that returns the `Report` for that `Station` with the most recent timestamp.

### Partial Schema

```
Stations
--------
Id

Reports
---------
Id
StationId
Timestamp
```

### Partial Code

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
}

public class Station : Entity
{
    public virtual IList<Report> Reports { get; private set; }

    public Station()
    {
        Reports = new List<Report>();
    }
}

public class Report : Entity
{
    public virtual Station Station { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}

public StationMap : ClassMap<Station>
{
    public StationMap()
    {
        Id(s => s.Id);
        HasMany<Report>(s => s.Reports)
            .Table("Reports")
            .KeyColumn("StationId");
    }
}

public ReportMap : ClassMap<Report>
{
    public ReportMap()
    {
        Id(r => r.Id);
        References<Station>(r => r.Station, "StationId");
        Map(r => r.Timestamp);
    }
}
```

I naively tried adding an unmapped property that returned `Reports.OrderByDescending(r => r.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault()` but that causes "could not resolve property: MostRecentReport" `NHibernate.QueryException`s (even though I am not using auto mapping). I also tried implementing it as a method with identical return, but that causes "Index was out of range" exceptions.

Is there a way to make it work with either the property (preferable) or method approach? Or is there some way to map it with `Formula()`, perhaps?

### Update

Fluent NHibernate configuration (occurs in my `NinjectModule` implementation's `Load` override):

```
ISessionFactory sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(Settings.ConnectionString))
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Domain.Station>())
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Let us see the code where you configure NHibernate. An automap might be lurking somewhere.

Comment: Updated question with Fluent NHibernate configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason that you would have to map a property like this -- NHibernate should just ignore it if you are not automapping.

I happen to agree with David's answer, that you might be breaking the abstraction of your domain model.

That said, I think the answer is that you have an NHibernate query (HQL/Criteria/LINQ) somewhere (a repository?) that is trying to access this property. That is, it isn't in the mappings that is the problem, it is in trying to use `MostRecentReport` when querying the database/cache.

Comment: Yeah, I was ignorantly using MostRecentReport in an IQueryable constraint and NHibernate was barfing on it because it wasn't mapped. And you were both right that it was an unnecessary property. After I thought about it, it was a pretty simple query to get the same data from a Reports angle rather than a Stations angle.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that adding unmapped properties to your Entities is such a good idea.  It's a better separation of concerns to add convenience properties to a ViewModel and use a repository query to get the value.